# Double direct code inclusion in iOS product possibility

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, swift-package-manager, xcode-project

Our project at work depends on a dynamic library that is called "LibraryAlpha". Also, our project at work depends on a dynamic library that is called "LibraryBeta". And also, it just so happens to be that "LibraryBeta" also depends on "LibraryAlpha".

Our project embeds .framework's built by different, i.e. embeds targets from  separate .xcodeproj's.

What are the chances of symbols and implementations (functions and classes) of "LibraryAlpha" in this or another way being embedded in the bundle of our project twice in the following cases:

- "LibraryAlpha"'s project target embedded into project's bundle, "LibraryAlpha"'s project target embedded into "LibraryBeta"'s bundle.
- "LibraryAlpha"'s project target embedded into project's bundle, "LibraryAlpha"'s source code statically linked with the source code of "LibraryBeta"
- "LibraryAlpha"'s project target embedded into project's bundle, with "LibraryBeta" only linking against, without embedding, "LibraryAlpha"

Additionally, it's commonly expected for .xcodeproj's produced with SPM to feature dependencies modules' as separate targets in the project which are linked against and embedded in the main (that one that declares its dependencies) module's bundle. So the question is, what happens if in our project I link and embed "LibraryAlpha" not as a target from a project "LibraryAlpha", but that one generated target for "LibraryAlpha"'s files in the project of "LibraryBeta"?

Comment: that's complicated !

Comment: @Fattie Is this comment noting that there is something wrong with the question?... or that it's just not something you answer in just a second?

Comment: means "Great question!  Tough one!"

Comment: @Fattie I would like to say that I've added a proper answer, just in case if you would like to read it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is wrong. Some cases presented in it can not be reproduced in real life.

Firstly, the concept that was mentioned in the question of "one framework linking against **and embedding** another framework" is not even a thing-- in fact, the whole concept of dynamic linkage was elevated in pursue of reusing same shared objects between multiple users, without the need to make the same code available (read, embed) more than once.

#### Case 1

Keeping previous statement in mind, the first case becomes literally impossible to reproduce in real life right away since the case states

> "LibraryAlpha"'s project target embedded into "LibraryBeta"'s bundle.

"LibraryBeta" might be linked against "LibraryAlpha"'s project target and in order to use "LibraryBeta" at runtime, the executable needs to embed the "LibraryAlpha". The repetition of symbols is unachievable here since "LibraryAlpha" will appear in bundle only once.

#### Case 2

> "LibraryAlpha"'s source code statically linked with the source code of "LibraryBeta"

This case will lead to repetition of code being compiled. Once it will be present in bundle in the form of dynamic library "LibraryAlpha" and once statically linked to "LibraryBeta".

Caveat:

> Actually, in this case you will not be able to compile "LibraryBeta" at all, assuming any of your source code files declares at the top `import LibraryAlpha`. Modules in Swift can not be declared manually and their source code must reside in separate targets in order to be importable. The case features source code in the same module as "LibraryBeta", so the compiler will error out with `No such module LibraryAlpha`.

#### Case 3

> "LibraryBeta" only linking against, without embedding, "LibraryAlpha"

The actual working solution, won't cause any of code repetition.

#### Case 4

> ...link and embed "LibraryAlpha" not as a target from a project "LibraryAlpha", but that one generated target for "LibraryAlpha"'s files in the project of "LibraryBeta"

No code repetition will occur in this case.

#### Bonus round:

For the cases like 4th, except you thrive not to reuse targets.

By linking "LibraryBeta" against one dynamic library, but embedding another dynamic library... There are two outcomes. 
Hypothetically the same source code and same configuration should produce the same dynamic library, same .framework folders with same object code, .swiftmodule's, .swiftdoc's, dSYM's and everything, even if it's two different targets in different projects. So in case, if the resulting .framework's happened to be absolutely same 2 different compilations in 2 different projects as 2 different targets, then your executable i.e. our project should link to whichever .framework is present at runtime just fine!

However, if output of "LibraryAlpha"'s own target will be somewhat different from "LibraryBeta"'s "LibraryAlpha" target, well... memes... I didn't bother checking what would happen in this case. But the logic tips that whichever "LibraryAlpha" was included, will not link to the opposite target properly, and dynamic linkage will fail. If somebody would like to check this behavior yourself, be my guest.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to manage complex dependencies of .xcodeprojs' targets is, speaking in figures of the question, to **not to manage them at all**:

- Archive->Export->Install "LibraryAlpha"
- Archive->Export->Install "LibraryBeta", linking against installed "LibraryAlpha"
- Archive->Export->Install arbitrary amount of other libraries that all dynamically link against "LibraryAlpha"
- Embed and link against installed "LibraryAlpha", "LibraryBeta" and friends.

In order to simplify the management of dependencies in Apple-targeted projects, you are strongly advised to use a dependency manager such as [**Carthage**](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) or [**CocoaPods**](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods). Not only they will make deployment an automated paradise breeze, they will also help eliminating the need to globally install your frameworks into the hosting OS.

---

## Old, wrong answer:

- to have "LibraryAlpha" as a separate .xcodeproj with its own target to build itself
- to have "LibraryBeta" dynamically link against THAT particular "LibraryAlpha" target without embedding
- to have our project dynamically link to "LibraryBeta" and THAT particular "LibraryAlpha" target, obviously, embedding both.

This is not something that Swift Package Manager does while resolving dependencies and generating .xcodeproj. SPM would usually end up putting all source code in one project and creating a target for "LibraryAlpha" in it.

This way there is no code included multiple times and everything resolves on runtime just nicely.

This of course doesn't answer the question, the question is just out of interest. But it's an important thing to keep in mind.